# Enabling an anchor link to work with the spacebar

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have a back-to-top link that jumps to an anchor link on the page at the top of an accordion element - I have it working as a button for accessibility and clicking on it with the mouse works as expected but the space bar doesn't have the desired result and just scrolls down the page.

My JS for the anchor and setting the focus again is:

```
jQuery(function($){
$("#back-to-top-2").on("click", function () {
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("top2").offset().top}, 500);
            $("#et_pb_accordion_1").focus();
        });
});
```

How do I get the spacebar to the function call to act the same way as the on-click?

Comment: `$("top2")` targets `<top2></top2>` element which is an invalid HTML5 element. Did you mean to pass an ID selector instead? Do it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to listen for the keydown event on the element and check if the spacebar key (key code 32) was pressed.
try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#back-to-top-2").on("click keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.type === "click" || (event.type === "keydown" && event.keyCode === 32)) {
        if (event.type === "keydown") {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default spacebar scrolling behavior
        }

        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#top2").offset().top}, 500);
        $("#et_pb_accordion_1").focus();
    }
    });
});
```